# Extra method in template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write an templated class with some methods/operators etc.. Now when the class is of an specififc type i would like to have extra append methods specially suited for that type which arent there for any other type. I dont' want to copy all the code into an new class.

Example:

```
template<typename T>
class Buffer
{
    Buffer(const Buffer<Type> &Buffer) : mData(Buffer.mData)
    {               
    }

    Buffer<Type> Clone()
    {
    }

    void Append (T * aData)
    {
    }

    // this one should only be there when Type is an unsigned char
    void Append (wchar_t * aData)
    {
    }

}
```

is this at all possible?

Greetz,
Richard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a policy class to manage the interaction with the type, then your class doesn't really have to worry about the type that is passed in, an appropriate policy (and specialization of said policy) can contain all the logic specific to that type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename U>
struct append_policy
{
  template <typename BufferType>
  static void append(BufferType& buffer, U type)
  {
    std::cout << "default: append U" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <typename U>
struct append_policy<std::string, U>
{
  template <typename BufferType>
  static void append(BufferType& buffer, U type)
  {
    std::cout << "string: append U" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <>
struct append_policy<std::string, char>
{
  template <typename BufferType>
  static void append(BufferType& buffer, char type)
  {
    std::cout << "string: append char" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct foo
{
  template <typename U>
  void append(U a)
  {
    append_policy<T, U>::append(buffer, a);
  }

  std::vector<char> buffer;
};

int main(void)
{
  foo<std::string> f;
  std::string test("test");
  f.append(test);
  f.append('C');

  foo<int> f1;
  f1.append(0);

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: now allows you to append any type to any type of `MyClass`, and allows you to override specific combination of types, and potentially throw exceptions in other combinations which you don't want to support.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this would give me only one Append method and not two (or even more).

Comment: @Richard, now updated to show how to use a policy to append any type to any type, without having lots of overloads.

Comment: This is actually a very nice solution and very extensible, you could make it traits like. THanks for this solution i'm going for this one!!!

Answer (score 10):

Directly this is impossible. Full specialization is full specialization which means you must implement the specialized class from scratch. However I can suggest the following trick:

```
template<class T>
class CommonFunctionality
{
   //your methods here
};

template<class T>
class MyClass: public CommonFunctionality<T>
{
};

template<>
class MyClass<MyType>:public CommonFunctionality<MyType>
{
  public:
    //your extra method here
};
```

thanks to Mark's suggestion, here's what you can do with the clone method:

```
template<class T, class ActualType>
class CommonFunctionality
{
   //your methods here
   ActualType Clone(){...}
};

template<class T>
class MyClass: public CommonFunctionality<T, MyClass<T> >
{
};

template<>
class MyClass<MyType>:public CommonFunctionality<MyType, MyClass<MyType> >
{
  public:
    //your extra method here
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but wouldn't the Clone method return the wrong type back. The version without the extra method?

Comment: @Richard: Well, if Clone is your concern maybe you could remove it from CommonFunctionality and code it twice in the two classes?

Comment: Or use CRTP with an extra template parameter to the `CommonFunctionality` class.

Comment: @Armen: I think i will give your solution an go. If i'm right your option allows me to have extra constructors as well which Nawaz version doesn't allow for, and you never know when you need that ;).

Comment: Armen, that cloning function isn't trivial when you have never seen CRTP and you might want to add it to your answer: `ActualType Clone() {return new ActualType(static_cast<ActualType&>(*this);}`. `+1` from me anyway.

Comment: @Armen: I doesn't seem to be working. When i have an Append function in de derived class the Append function in de base class isn't visible. It is if i rename it to something else, but when the name is the same it isn't visible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want both functions available when `T` is `unsigned char`, then do this:

```
template<typename T>    
struct AddExtraAppend{}; //empty 

template<>              
struct AddExtraAppend<unsigned char> //T=unsigned char,so define a function
{
   void Append (wchar_t * aData)
   {
   }    
};

template<typename T>
class Buffer : AddExtraAppend<T>
{
   void Append (T * aData)
   {
   }    

   //Dont define Append(wchar_t *) here
   //Because if T is unsigned char, it will be inhereted from AddExtraAppend<>
};
```

This is the basic idea. You can combine it with [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to achieve your goal.

---

However, if you want just one function available, then you can do this.

First write a `param<>` class template as,

```
template<typename T> 
struct param { typedef T type; };

template<> //specialization to satisfy your requirement!
struct param<unsigned char> { typedef wchar_t type; };
```

Then, define just one function (instead of two) as:

```
void Append (typename param<T>::type * aData)
{
}
```

Comment: Won't this collide with the `void Append (T * aData)` version for any other type though (my reading of the question is for `unsigned char*` only he wants BOTH functions available)?

Comment: @Mark: There will be just one function!

Comment: Thanks for your time, isn`t this full specialization, and for that i have to write all the code over again. And i still want to have the other methods too.

Comment: @Richard: No. You need a class template `param`. You need to write your existing class all over again!

Comment: @Richard: Do you want both functions available when T is `unsigned char`?

Comment: @Richard: Please see my solution. See especially how `AddExtraAppend` class template is implemented.

Comment: @Nawaz, that looks realy nice, just tried it but how would AddExtraAppend acces the members of buffer? If you could fix that you would rock in my world ;).

Comment: @Richard: I can explain that. But I need to know if you know CRTP?

Comment: @Richard: Or, alternatively, you can move members to the `AddExtraAppend` base class.

Comment: @Nawaz, i think i understand that. But an base class can't access its derived members right? So would that mean i need to go for you option 2?

Comment: @Richard: If you use CRTP and make `AddExtraAppend` friend of derived class, then `AddExtraAppend` can access members of it's derived class, even private members!

Comment: @Nawaz: I can't seem to get it to work it compiles and links, but the extra method isn't visible!

Comment: @Nawaz: it seems that if the name of the function is the same, it isn't visible?

Comment: @Richard: No, you need to make it visible by writing `using AddExtraAppend<T>::Append;` in the derived class. But for this you also have to add a dummy function in the empty base class. There can be more elegant way to make it visible. I need to think about this. But right now, I'm kind of busy.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve is by having `Append()` out of `class Buffer`. Something like:

```
template <typename T>
void Append(Buffer<T>* pBuffer, T* pData);
```

and have a specialization like this:

```
template <>
void Append(Buffer<wchat_t>* pBuffer, wchar_t* pData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [partial specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html):

```
// --*-- C++ --*--

#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
class Buffer
{
public:
    Buffer () {}

    void Append (const T * aData)
    {
        printf ("Data ptr = %p\n", aData);
    }
};

// Special implementation for `wchar_t` case.
template <>
void Buffer<wchar_t>::Append (const wchar_t * aData)
{
    printf ("wchar_t ptr = %p\n", aData);
}

int main ()
{
    Buffer<char> a;
    a.Append (NULL);

    Buffer<wchar_t> b;
    b.Append (NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
template<class T1, class T2>
struct check_equal;

template<class T1>
struct check_equal<T1, T1> {};

template<typename T>
class Buffer
{
    int mData;
public:
    Buffer(): mData(0) {}
    Buffer(const Buffer<T> &buffer) : mData(buffer.mData) {}

    void Append (T * aData)
    {
    }

    void Append (wchar_t * aData)
    {
        check_equal<T, unsigned char>();
        // ...
    }
};
```

In that way you can't use `Append(wchar_t*)` member function if `T` is not `unsigned char`, because compiler won't allow it. And if you don't use the method compiler will optimize it, so it won't exist in code.

Check http://www.ideone.com/mh9Rk